# Migrate Blogger to GitHubPages/Jekyll

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, github-pages, blogger

I try to migrate my blog from Blogger to GitHubPages/Jekyll platform.

I follow the [installation instructions for the jekyll-import](https://import.jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/), but obtain the following result

```
myaccount.github.io> gem install jekyll-import
Fetching jekyll-import-0.19.2.gem
Fetching mini_portile2-2.4.0.gem
Fetching nokogiri-1.10.9-x64-mingw32.gem
Fetching reverse_markdown-1.4.0.gem
Successfully installed mini_portile2-2.4.0
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll-import:
        The last version of nokogiri (~> 1.0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.10.9. Try installing it with `gem install nokogiri -v 1.10.9` and then running the current command again
        nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.3, < 2.7.dev. The current ruby version is 2.7.0.0.
```

It seems my just installed Ruby version is too fresh...

Declared [nokogiri issue is here](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/2017)
please help

Comment: How did you install Ruby? If you're using a manager like rbenv, you could just install v2.6 in the working directory: `rbenv install 2.6.x` and then `rbenv local 2.6.x`

Comment: why should I install v2.6? I don't know ruby at all, I installed from the windows installer the latest version that seems to be 2.7.0.0

Comment: If the tool you want to use doesn't work with your installed version, installing a different version seems like the quickest win, no? If that's unappealing, there are a few things you could try in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1961

Comment: I installed the ruby 2.6.5 but this time I run into another problem https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-import/issues/431

Comment: too much issues for such a small importer...